# Question about this proof of the minimum distance between a closed and a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to prove that for some metric space $X$ there is a positive real number $\epsilon$ such that $d(x,y) \geq \epsilon$ for all $x \in A$ and $y \in B$, where A is a closed set and B, is compact and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. But, I have a question about the final part of my proof concerning equality.

I proved this by noting any element of $p \in B \subset$ X-A is not a limit point of A since A is closed, so there is some $p \in B$, $r > 0$ where $B(p,r) \cap A = \emptyset$. Then we can arbitrarily let $d(p,A) > 2\sigma_{p}$. The collection of open balls centered at every $p \in B$ with radius $\sigma_{p}$ is an open cover of B, since B is compact there are finitely many balls centered at $p_{i}$ with radius $\sigma_{p_{i}}$ that form an open covering of B. Then we can take $\sigma =$ min$(\sigma_{p_{1}},...,\sigma_{p_{n}})$ and for some $p_{i}$ in B then for some $y \in A$ and $b \in B$

$d(p_{i},y) \leq d(p_{i},b) + d(b,y) < \sigma_{i} + d(b,y)$

then

$d(b,y) > d(p_{i},y) - \sigma_{i} > 2\sigma_{i}-\sigma{i} = \sigma_{i} \geq \sigma$

$\therefore$ We have $d(b,y) > \sigma$

However, the question asks for $d(x,y) \geq \epsilon$ not $d(x,y) > \epsilon$, could anyone guide me as to how I can come up with an equality case or from where I could redo the proof to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d(x,y)>\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, then trivially $d(x,y)\ge\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in B$, so you have nothing more to prove: the latter statement is true even if there are no $x\in A$ and $y\in B$ such that $d(x,y)=\epsilon$.

As for the proof itself, you have the right idea, but parts of the argument are stated incorrectly.

> I proved this by noting any element of $p \in B \subset$ X-A is not a limit point of A since A is closed, so there is some $p \in B$, $r > 0$ where $B(p,r) \cap A = \emptyset$.

No, what you need here is that for **each** $p\in B$ there is an $r_p>0$ such that $B(p,r_p)\cap A=\varnothing$.

> Then we can arbitrarily let $d(p,A) > 2\sigma_{p}$.

What you mean is that since $d(p,A)>r_p$, we can let $\sigma_p=\frac{r_p}2$, so that $d(p,A)>2\sigma_p$.

> The collection of open balls centered at every $p \in B$ with radius $\sigma_{p}$ is an open cover of B, since B is compact there are finitely many balls centered at $p_{i}$ with radius $\sigma_{p_{i}}$ that form an open covering of B.

This is okay, though I’d state it a bit more carefully: $\{B(p,\sigma_p):p\in B\}$ is an open cover of $B$, and $B$ is compact, so there is a finite $\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}\subseteq B$ such that $\{B(p_i,\sigma_i):i=1,\ldots,n\}$ covers $B$. Note that you do need to mention $n$ at this point, since you want to use it later when you define $\sigma$.

> Then we can take $\sigma =$ min$(\sigma_{p_{1}},...,\sigma_{p_{n}})$ and for some $p_{i}$ in B then for some $y \in A$ and $b \in B$ $$d(p_{i},y) \leq d(p_{i},b) + d(b,y) < \sigma_{i} + d(b,y)$$

No, you want to show something about **every** $y\in A$, not **some** $y\in A$. Let $y\in A$ and $b\in B$. There is some $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ such that $b\in B(p_i,\epsilon_i)$; then you can finish the argument exactly as you did.